# How can I use my Pinia store in a Nuxt 3 server API?

Tags: api, nuxtjs3, pinia

I'm creating a server API, following the docs: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server

I need this endpoint to use data from a Pinia store. But when importing and using my store, I get an error:

```
import {useUserStore} from "~/stores/user"

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const userStore = useUserStore()
    console.log(userStore.userData)
})
```

```
[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] []: getActivePinia was called with no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?
```

I also tried using `useNuxtApp()` but it fails with `useNuxtApp is not defined` :(

Answer (score 0):

Calling `pinia` inside the `server` folder gives you an error. My understanding is the server runs before pinia. I'm not 100% sure.

If you want to get the user from your `server` route. You can create a nuxt plugin inside the `plugins` folder.

I'll create an example here. I tested it on my machine and it works.

- `~/stores/user.ts`

```js
// stores -> user.ts
export const useUser = defineStore('useUser', {
 state: () => {
  return {
    userData: '' as any,
  }
 },
})
```

- `plugins/user.server.ts`

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin(async () => {
 const user = useUser()
 const data = await $fetch('/api/user')
 user.userData = data
})
```

- `~/server/api/user.get.ts`

```js
export default defineEventHandler(() => {
 return {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  email: 'john@gmail.com'
 }
})
```

- `app.vue`

```js
<script setup lang=ts>
const user = useUser()
</script>
<template>
 <div>
  {{ user.userData }}
 </div>
</template>
```

And the result is this
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your example; but it doesn't use the Pinia store in the server API endpoint, right?

Comment: As far as I know you cannot use pinia inside the server api endpoint because the way I understand it, the server will run first before pinia.